# Actionscript old script _root.link

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, root, movieclip

About 4 years ago I used a flash template with action script to design a website. When it came to navigation from movieclip to movieclip in frame s1 the following code was used:

```
    gotoAndPlay("s1");
}
on (releaseOutside, rollOut) {
    gotoAndPlay("s2");
}
on (release) {
    if (_root.link<>23 and _root.flag == 1) {
        _parent["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s2");
        _root.link =23;
        _root.flag = 0;
        _root.pgap.play();
        _parent["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s1");
    }
}
```

As you can see there are two frames s2 and s1. It uses root.link.

So I need to add a navigation to newly created movie clip (becuae they don't want to redesign the site with new scripting like php)

The last _root.link was 23, so I thought ok add 24 to go to the movie clip(shown within frame s1). Nope didn't show new movie clip. HOWEVER any other numbers show the correct movie clip (within frame s1).

So I forget! How do I navigate to a new symbol(movie clip) I created from another movie clips shown in frame s1 ?

I forget why root.link=1,2,3,4,5,etc ?

My memory is a blur so anyhelp would be great!

Comment: I would think that I would need to call the movieclip by its name and not number (like 24). How does the script above know where to navigate?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered I needed to put the movieclip on the timeline. The root.link= # is the frame number. Ah sorry for wasting everyones time!